# Tap/click on select element not working on mobile device with Ionic Framework

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a simple *select* element for choose the app language. This is the view code:

```
<ion-view title={{i18n.settings.title}}>
  <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
    <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
  <ion-content >
    <div class="list">
      <label class="item item-input item-select">
        <div class="input-label" >
          {{i18n.settings.select_language}}
        </div>
        <select class="ion-input-select" ng-model="language" ng-change="changeLanguage(language)">
          <option value="es">{{i18n.settings.spanish}}</option>
          <option value="en">{{i18n.settings.english}}</option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

The expected result is of course, click on the *select* and options should be shown:
[image]

It works perfectly if I open the app in a desktop browser (I'm using Chrome) and click the select with the mouse.

The thing is, I have a touch-screen laptop, so if I try to tap the select with my finger it doesn't work. The same occurs if I open the app in a mobile device (Android 6) browser (using also Chrome).

More specifically, it only works if I tap with my finger approximately over the red rectangle I've marked in the attached image, but not if I top on the rest of the *select* element.

**Note 1**: There's not any CSS for this view that could create some conflict with the *select* behaviour.
**Note 2**: I don't receive any error on the console

**Ionic version: 1.1.0**

Answer (score 1):

It seems that after **update the Ionic Framework version from 1.1.0 to 1.3.2**, the error has been fixed.

Now it works fine in every dispositve: touch-screen laptop, desktop-browser, mobile device browser and android APK

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the div :

```
 <div class="input-label" >
          {{i18n.settings.select_language}}
        </div>
        <select class="ion-input-select" ng-model="language" ng-change="changeLanguage(language)">
          <option value="es">{{i18n.settings.spanish}}</option>
          <option value="en">{{i18n.settings.english}}</option>
        </select>
```

to label with text and select control:

```
<label class = "item item-input item-select">
   <div class = "input-label">
       {{i18n.settings.select_language}}
   </div>

   <select class="ion-input-select" ng-model="language" ng-change="changeLanguage(language)">
              <option value="es">{{i18n.settings.spanish}}</option>
              <option value="en">{{i18n.settings.english}}</option>
            </select>
</label>
```

Comment: Sorry, that was my first approach as is indicated in the Ionic documentation when you use a *select* element. I'll update the code with te original code (with the *label* element), which still doesn't work